# python sentiment analysis not defined error and Ran out of input error

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I have run the two code segment of this(http://pythonprogramming.net/sentiment-analysis-module-nltk-tutorial/) tutorial and getting  2 errors from code segment 1 and 2.

for code segment 1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sampath/Desktop/tute/sta.py", line 68, in 
    pickle.dump(documents, save_classifier)
NameError: name 'save_classifier' is not defined

for code segment 2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sampath/Desktop/tute/sta.py", line 40, in 
    documents = pickle.load(documents_f)
EOFError: Ran out of input

please help.

training data set files from here
http://pythonprogramming.net/static/downloads/short_reviews/

Answer (score 0):

When you get a traceback, look at the code where the error occurred and try to determine why you get the error.  The NameError means just what it says.  The context:

```
save_documents = open("pickled_algos/documents.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(documents, save_classifier)
save_documents.close()
```

This is the first occurrence of `save_classifier`, and it is not bound to any object at this point.  It should be `save_documents`.  Please go to `Contact` at the bottom of the page and let them know of this bug in the code they display.

The EOFError is at

```
documents_f = open("pickled_algos/documents.pickle", "rb")
documents = pickle.load(documents_f)
documents_f.close()
```

Since the file was opened (first snippet), it exists.  Since nothing was written, due to the bug, it is empty.  Rerun this after rerunning the corrected first snippet.

Comment: thanks for your consideration.i tried it by adding some data (bytes) to the documents.pickle.so that's mean now it's not empty.but again it shows EOFError: Ran out of input.